# The upload path does not appear to be valid”. Codeigniter file upload

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx';
        $config['max_size'] = '400';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

  $this->referral_model->postCVReferralInfo($m_id, $emp_id , $job_id, $name, $age , $gender,$country_id, $mobile, $email, $summary, $workExp, $education, $qualification, $offer, $sb_id);
    header('location:'.$this->config->base_url().'index.php/member/referSuccess');

    exit;



    } `
```

If I try to upload the doc file then I'm getting this error "The upload path does not appear to be valid". I replaced the path to absolute Path then also I am getting this error.
please suggest me how I can resolve the issue.`

Comment: where is your upload folder on a root???

Comment: uploads folder is inside the main folder (where application folder, image folder etc are placed inside the main folder)

Comment: Make sure that the directory is writeable. What chmod is set on it?

Comment: directory is writable .

Comment: CodeIgniter will only return that error message if `$config['upload_path']` is blank (which it is not) or the php command `is_dir(upload_path)` returns false. So this indicates that the path defined can not be found. Check to make sure the 'uploads' folder is in the same directory as main index.php file and that the directory name is the same case (i.e. uploads not Uploads)

Answer (score 15):

The problem usually occurs when a call to `$this->load->library('upload', $config)`, may be it does not load the configuration settings, so try adding the following statement after loading the upload library.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 7):

Same problem...solved by

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

And better not to use....BASE_URL in `$CONFIG['UPLOAD_PATH']`

Comment: Yes in my case also the BASE_URL was the problem

Answer (score 2):

never use base_url() in $CONFIG['UPLOAD_PATH'],

Take note of the dot before the backslash preceding your upload folder. Hence your upload path should look like this

```
 $CONFIG['UPLOAD_PATH'] = './assets/uploads/
```

Answer (score 1):

better use:

```
$config["upload_path"] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your/desired/location/";
```

And initialize your config by:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this `$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';`

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same error, here's my code.

```
        // Upload Image
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '7048';
        $config['max_width'] = '7000';
        $config['max_height'] = '7000';

        // Create folder (Uploads) if not exists
        if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
            mkdir($config['upload_path']);
        }

        // Load library Upload
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        // Initialize the Upload library with curront $config
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $this->upload->do_upload();
        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $page_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        } else {
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $page_image = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $this->page_model->create_page($page_image);

        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('page_created', 'Your page has been created');

        redirect('admin/pages/create');
```

try to past

```
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

just after loading the library Upload

```
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with uplaods in the root directory and use following code in controller

```
$config['upload_path'] =  'uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 2000;
$config['max_width'] = 1500;
$config['max_height'] = 1500;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic')) 
{
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}else{
   $data = array('image_metadata' => $this->upload->data());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**look after this line: **
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

```
    **Then add this short code**
```

$this->upload->initialize($config);

UPLOAD SUCCESSFULL

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777172/2227743).